# Use Electron in Vue project

Tags: vue.js, electron

I want put my Vue project in the Electron, so I find the method in the Internet. According to the given method on the Intenet, I make a demo to test it.
At frist, I create Vue project using `vue create myProject`, then I use `vue add electron-builder` to add Electron, then I choose the Electron version, then it prepare to install the additional dependencies. But the error is there：[image]

Someone could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try [electron-webpack](https://webpack.electron.build/). You will not only need to add Vue to your electron Project but handle proper file access and sass compile, etc. This can be tricky. But however your error seems to be a connection refuse on localhost port 443. Dig in deeper on that.

Answer (score 0):

[electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue): An Electron & Vue.js quick start boilerplate with vue-cli scaffolding.

maybe you can try it.